# choosing a selection from an array, and carrying a numerical value over to another page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a novice at PHP, so I'm having trouble with this task:

In a nutshell, I want to run a query and have the results returned in an array, and then allow the users to choose one selection from the array, and have a numerical value get passed on to another php page to be used in additional computations.

Here's my basic code so far:

```
<?php
 include 'mysql_connect.php';
      $Choices = mysqli_query ($server_connect, "SELECT * FROM Database 
WHERE FLOOR (Item_number) = '$StockCategory' AND name='$name'") 
or die(mysqli_error ($server_connect));?>

            <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" width="20%" border="1">
            <?php while ($selectionlist = mysqli_fetch_array($Choices)){
$orderchoicenumber++; 
$selectnumber = $matchups['Item_number']; ?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $selectionlist['size']; ?> </td>
<td>   <?php echo $selectionlist['color'];?> </td>
<td>   <?php echo $selectnumber;?></td>
<td>   <?php echo $orderchoicenumber;?>
                <?php }?>
</td></tr>

   Enter your selection: 

<form name ="selectionprocess" action="precheckout.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" maxlength="2" name="enterselection" >
<input type="hidden" name="selectnumber" value="<?php echo $selectnumber;?>">
</form>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" >
```

and here's the code on the destination page [precheckout.php]:

```
<?php
 $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : $_SESSION['name'];
    $mode = $_POST["select"];
       $SelectNumber = $_POST["selectnumber"]; 

       $Item_number = $SelectNumber;
?>
<p>Hello <?php echo $name; ?>!</p> <br>
OK, the item number of what you want is--- <?php echo $Item_number;?>
```

Of course, this means the number of results from the myfetcharray will vary.

The first aspect works pretty well. In this example, here's the output I receive (in table format):

Enter your selection: _____

4x6     navy    90515.01    1

4x8     mauve       90515.07    2

6x8     auburn      90515.03    3

2x4     black   90515.02    4

5x7     aqua        90515.08    5

The selection number is in the far right column. (The decimal number is the identifying Item Number in my SQL database. I'd like to not display this number in the final program, and even though I suppose I could make users enter in that number instead of a selection number in order to proceed, it's not a very user-friendly approach.)

The problem arises when I try to enter in a selection number (in this case, 1-5). The program successfully carries over a numerical value to the precheckout page `[value="<?php echo $selectnumber;?>">]`, *but it's always the final value spit out by the myfetcharray (i.e. in the lowest row).* In this example, the output on the next page would be:

### Hello, John!

### OK, let's see how you did, because this item number is--- 90515.08

...no matter which matchup number was selected.

Ideally, I would like a more user-friendly way of selecting a row, rather than typing in a selection number. I've tried the radio button approach, but the best I could do was to successfully pass along a value of "on" to the next page instead of a numerical value. I'm willing to use other languages, though I don't know if they would play nice with PHP (i.e., Javascript).

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off: a more user-friendly approach could be a dropdown menu: Try this:

```
<select>
<?php while ($selectionlist = mysqli_fetch_array($Choices)){
$orderchoicenumber++; 
$selectnumber = $matchups['Item_number']; ?>
<option value="<?php echo $selectnumber; ?>"> 
<?php echo $selectionlist['size'] . " " . $selectionlist['color'] . " " . $selectionlist['color'] . " " . $selectnumber . " " . $orderchoicenumber; ?>
</option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

All your PHP code is executed on the server when the page loads and any user interaction with the page is 'client side' (on the user's machine) so you're right: it needs another language to update your selectnumber hidden input. jQuery (a javascript library) is your best bet here.

You must already have some javascript on your page to post your form to precheckout.php - can you add that to your question, then I'll be able to guide you on the bits you need to change?

Comment: Thomas - Thanks for your response. The drop-down menu is indeed a much better option. But I do not have any javascript on my page. I was relying on the final "form-related" lines of code to POST it to the next page. Like I said, the actual POST function worked - it just passed along the wrong value.

Comment: Ahh! I see what you're doing now. Apologies for the confusion.

To post the dropdown menu, remove the two <input> tags from your form, and move the <select> tag to within your form - you should then get the value attribute of the selected option posted - you can change that by changing the PHP echo and that should sort you out :)